# Find the multiplicative inverse in the Field $F_5[x]/(x^ 2 + x + 1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the multiplicative inverse of $x + 1$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^
2 + x + 1)$

## My  attempt:

First  i take  $px+q$ ($p,q \in \Bbb F_{5}$) which is multiplicative inverse of $x+ 1$ in $\frac {\Bbb F_{5}[x]}{\langle x^2+x+ 1 \rangle}$.

i.e. $[(x+1)+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle][(px+q)+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle]=1+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$

$\Rightarrow$

$(x+1)(px+q)+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle=1+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$

$\Rightarrow$

$px^2+(q+p)x+q+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle=1+\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$.

We see that the remainder,when $(x+1)(px+q)$ is divided by $x^2+x+1$, is $1$.
So by Division algorithm,

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
p \\[-3pt]
x^2+x+1 \enclose{longdiv}{px^2+(q+p)x+q} \\[-3pt]
\underline{px^2+px+p} \\[-3pt]
(qx+(q-p) \\[-3pt]
\end{array}
$$

So I equate $qx+(q-p)=1$ and solve the simultaneous linear equations

$qx=0, q-p=1$. I get $p=4,q=5$

Hence $4x+5$ that  is  in the  form $px  + q$ is the required inverse.

Is  My answer  correct or not

Is there  any  other rule to find the  inverse ??

Comment: It is correct, but it would be much easier if you noticed that $$0=x^2+x+1=x(x+1)+1\,,$$ whence $$(-x)(x+1)=1\,.$$

Comment: thanks  @Batominovski.  but  how (-x)  come  in ur  last equation

Comment: Well, $x(x+1)+1=0$ implies $-x(x+1)=1$.

Comment: And note that in $\mathbb{F}_5$, $4x+5 = -x$.

Comment: Another method would be to use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the gcd of $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ is 1, and find $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $a(x) (x+1) + b(x) (x^2+x+1) = 1$; then the congruence class of $a(x)$ is the multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Here are some similar questions that have been posted in the past: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092716/find-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial-in-a-quotient-ring), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068641/multiplicative-inverse-of-2x-3-i-in-mathbbz-5x-i), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963526/expressing-alpha-1-1-where-alpha3-alpha2-alpha2-0) .